# How to replace a hyperlink with a word in table created with kableExtra and display it in a pdf document

Tags: r, pdf, kableextra

Hi i have this example dataframe in the .rmd document below which i want to display as a table with the `kableExtra` package. The problem is that i cannot replace the urls of the second column with the "linkname" of the first and still keep them working as hyperlinks in a pdf document.

````
---
title: "Clinical Table"
author: EK
date: January 29, 2018
output: 
  pdf_document: 
  keep_tex: yes
---

```{r nice-tab, tidy=FALSE,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE} 
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
  df<-data.frame(rep("linkname",10))
df$url<- c("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadillac_Fleetwood",
           "https://www.lincoln.com/luxury-cars/continental/",
           "http://shop.honda.com/civics.aspx",
           "https://bringatrailer.com/2011/12/28/striking-1973-maserati-bora-4-9/",
           "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadillac_Fleetwood",
           "https://www.lincoln.com/luxury-cars/continental/",
           "http://shop.honda.com/civics.aspx",
           "https://bringatrailer.com/2011/12/28/striking-1973-maserati-bora-4-9/",
           "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadillac_Fleetwood",
           "https://www.lincoln.com/luxury-cars/continental/")
names(df)[1]<-"name"

df$name<- paste("<a href=\"",df$url,"\">",df$name,"</a>",sep="")


kable(
  df, caption = 'REPORT TABLE',
  booktabs = TRUE,format = "latex",escape = FALSE
)%>%
kable_styling(full_width = T)

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you are trying to have one column "name" that links to the listed sites but only displays the "linkname" as opposed to the full url.

Try the below.

```
df<-data.frame(name = rep("linkname",10))
url<- c("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadillac_Fleetwood",
       "https://www.lincoln.com/luxury-cars/continental/",
       "http://shop.honda.com/civics.aspx",
       "https://bringatrailer.com/2011/12/28/striking-1973-maserati-bora-4-9/",
       "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadillac_Fleetwood",
       "https://www.lincoln.com/luxury-cars/continental/",
       "http://shop.honda.com/civics.aspx",
       "https://bringatrailer.com/2011/12/28/striking-1973-maserati-bora-4-9/",
       "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadillac_Fleetwood",
       "https://www.lincoln.com/luxury-cars/continental/")

df$name <- paste0("[", df$name, "](", url, ")")

knitr::kable(df)
```

Comment: Im afraid that it does not work with this option knitr::kable(df,format = "latex")

Comment: i do not think you need to include the format option. You have already declared your rmd to output pdf. format will be automatically determined if the function is called within knitr. when you "knit" your rmd to pdf output it should produce the desired format automatically.

Comment: ok there was another issue irrelevant with this which i fixed so i can accept your answer.Tnx